# Using SQLite, how can I search for chars that include a '?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Using SQLite, how can I search for chars that include a '?

This works to find bruce and baseball:

```
string stCmdString = "SELECT fstInfo FROM PadTable WHERE fstInfo LIKE '%bruce%' AND fstInfo LIKE '%baseball%'"
```

Not sure how to find bruce's and baseball.

Comment: Double them to escape: `... where fld = 'bruce''s'` **but** you should be using a parameterized query which will a) do this for you and b) secure you from SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2):

You escape the apostrophe with another apostrophe:

```
string stCmdString = "SELECT fstInfo FROM PadTable WHERE fstInfo LIKE '%bruce''s%' AND fstInfo LIKE '%baseball%'"
```

Comment: I know it can be done by using two quote marks ... but this is a bit of a hassle to read every char of all new entries (or searches) to the database before storing the.

The use of .Parameters in OLE DB fixes this problem.  Is there an equivalent for SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

The Parameters feature allows the use of words that have ' in the word.

```
using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand sqliteCmd = sqliteConnection.CreateCommand()) 
{ 
  sqliteCmd.CommandText = "SELECT" + stFieldNames + "FROM " + stTableName + " WHERE " + stLikeFieldName + " LIKE '%' || @p0 || '%'";
  sqliteCmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@p0", liststLikeFieldValue[0]));
  for (int iii = 1; iii < liststLikeFieldValue.Count; iii++) 
  {
    sqliteCmd.CommandText += " AND " + stLikeFieldName + " LIKE '%' || @p" + iii.ToString() + " || '%'";
    sqliteCmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@p" + iii.ToString(), liststLikeFieldValue[iii]));
  }
```